# How to get content inside div with Regex - PHP

Tags: javascript, php, regex, preg-match

```
<div class="hello">

<span>Hello World<span>

<div>
```

I need to get all content inside the div.

I tried this way, but I can not get:

[image: regex101 screenshot]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Comment: You wouldn't use a hammer to drill holes into wood. Why use regex to parse  XML? But anyway, to answer your question `.` matches any character *except newline characters*. Use the `s` modifier

Comment: In the future use the `save regex` option and provide the link... and preferably the code here as well.

Comment: @douglas I bet you are not using single line flag. Do you?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
/(<div class="hello">){1}(.)*(<\/div>){1}/is
```

The 's' flag allows the dot (.) to match newline.  Then you will get the three groupings that you desire.

See https://regex101.com/r/dlrbhM/2 for a live example

Comment: As correct as this is (I noted this in my comment about 10 minutes ago), this is not a good answer as HTML should very seldom be parsed with regex (by seldom, I mean pretty much never)

Comment: Revised to remove redundant/unnecessary flags

Comment: I agree with what you are saying @ctwheels, but the OP didn't ask for the best way to do it, just "how" to do it.